# Не удаётся извлечь значения из массива при помощи двух циклов

Tags: javascript, циклы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Мне нужно из этого массива [1, 4, 5, 9, 2, 5, 1] вывести в консоль все неповторяющиеся значения - [4, 9, 2]. Я пытаюсь сделать это при помощи двух циклов и ожидаю, что первый цикл будет по очереди сравнивать числа (i) с числами (j) из второго цикла. И я рассчитываю на 7 итераций:

```
1) i = 0 | j = 1; j = 2; j = 3; j = 4; j = 5; j = 6 | - в консоль не выведется
2) i = 1 | j = 0; j = 2; j = 3; j = 4; j = 5; j = 6 | - console.log(4)
3) i = 2 | j = 0; j = 1; j = 3; j = 4; j = 5; j = 6 | - в консоль не выведется
4) i = 3 | j = 0; j = 1; j = 2; j = 4; j = 5; j = 6 | - console.log(9)
5) i = 4 | j = 0; j = 1; j = 2; j = 3; j = 5; j = 6 | - console.log(2)
6) i = 5 | j = 0; j = 1; j = 2; j = 3; j = 4; j = 6 | - в консоль не выведется
7) i = 6 | j = 0; j = 1; j = 2; j = 3; j = 4; j = 5 | - в консоль не выведется
```

Но вместо этого получается другой результат (на скриншоте). Помогите, пожалуйста, мне разобраться, что здесь не так (если возможно, то как можно проще).

```
var numbers = [1, 4, 5, 9, 2, 5, 1];

for (var i = 0; i <= numbers.length - 1; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j <= numbers.length - 1 && j != i; j++) {
    if (numbers[i] != numbers[j]) {
      console.log(numbers[i]);
    }
  } 
}[![Результат работы циклов][1]][1]
```

В предложенном вопросе решение находится путём создания функции, я же попросил помочь с решением этой задачи при помощи циклов (если это возможно).

Comment: array.filter((v, i, s) => s.indexOf(v) === s.lastIndexOf(v))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваше условие `if (numbers[i] != numbers[j])` срабатывает всегда.

Как это исправить в вашем коде:

```js
var numbers = [1, 4, 5, 9, 2, 5, 1];

for (var i = 0; i <= numbers.length - 1; i++) {
  var exist = false;
  for (var j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
    if (numbers[i] === numbers[j] && j !== i) {
      exist = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (exist === false) console.log(numbers[i]);
}
```

Ещё есть более короткий способ:

```js
var numbers = [1, 4, 5, 9, 2, 5, 1];

var filter_numbers = numbers.filter(function(value, i, arr) {
  return arr.indexOf(value) === arr.lastIndexOf(value);
});
console.log(filter_numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если кому-нибудь пригодится, вот решение при помощи одного цикла.

```
var numbers = [1, 4, 5, 9, 2, 5, 1];

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  if (numbers.indexOf(numbers[i]) === numbers.lastIndexOf(numbers[i])) {
    console.log(numbers[i]);
  }
}
```